# How to control execution order of flyway repeatable scripts

Tags: flyway

Is there any way to control execution order of repeatable migration scripts in flyway?
I want to run a repeatable migration script after all other repeatable or versioned scripts on checksum change.

Comment: I didnot understand your requirement but i guess you are looking for a way to perform migrations without any order .If that is what you need use this "outOfOrder" .Set this value to true

Comment: But there is a potential problem with this option.Verify your migration files with the schema_version table for any missed scripts .

Comment: We can specify execution order of versioned migration scripts simply by setting version number. But I didn't find any way to sort execution of repeatable migration scripts. My question was about repeatable migrations. outOfOrder is about versioned mirgrations.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Repeatable scripts appear to be controlled by the name following the `R__` `suffix`, `first numeric`, then `alpha upper case`, then `alpha lower case`.

> Instead of being run just once, they are (re-)applied every time their checksum changes.
>
> Within a single migration run, repeatable migrations are always applied last, after all pending versioned migrations have been executed.

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#repeatable-migrations

Comment: For what flyway calls *repeatable* scripts, you can specify order by doing the following: R__01_mustberunfirst.sql, R__02_mustberunsecond.sql etc...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe naming the scripts in the right order is not enough. If you name them `R__A`, `R__B` and `R__C`, it works for the first time, but when you later only change `R__B`, then only `R__B` will be executed. This may be a problem, if subsequent scripts should be re-executed but did not change. For example, `R__B` creates a table and `R__C` inserts some static data.

Comment: Then what else should be done to control the order? Stating that something does not work does not look like a solution for the problem

Comment: The aforementioned problem can now be solved with the built-in `${flyway:timestamp}` substitution, which may be added before each repeatable migration (_e.g._ as an SQL comment).

Comment: It `R__B` creates a table, it shouldn't be a repeatable script in the first place.. And if it was and `R__C` would insert some static data, it would pretty surely also have to be changed. In short: examples matter, if your use case is built on anti patterns, they don't make a good case for missing functionality...